# OpenWeather Onecall API

Tags: flutter, api, dart, openweathermap

I want to get the City Name according to the user location, current weather and the weather for the rest of the week using Onecall API, but I can't find the **City Name** in the **Onecall API**, there is only a **Timezone** which is not useful. Is there any other way to get the City Name??
Here is the JSON API response:

```json
{
  "lat": 33.44,
  "lon": -94.04,
  "timezone": "America/Chicago",
  "timezone_offset": -18000,
  "current": {
    "dt": 1633679614,
    "sunrise": 1633695331,
    "sunset": 1633737084,
    "temp": 292.71,
    "feels_like": 292.6,
    "pressure": 1017,
    "humidity": 72,
    "dew_point": 287.53,
    "uvi": 0,
    "clouds": 0,
    "visibility": 10000,
    "wind_speed": 1.34,
    "wind_deg": 180,
    "wind_gust": 2.24,
    "weather": [
      {
        "id": 800,
        "main": "Clear",
        "description": "clear sky",
        "icon": "01n"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This information is not present. Use geocoding to get your city.

Answer (score 0):

The Open Weather - One API has the functionality you asked for using users lat and lang:

> [https://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/onecall?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&exclude={part}&appid={APIkey}](https://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/onecall?lat=%7Blat%7D&lon=%7Blon%7D&exclude=%7Bpart%7D&appid=%7BAPIkey%7D)

Reference:

> https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-3

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library - [weather_pack](https://pub.dev/packages/weather_pack). There are currently two APIs available:

- `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather`
- `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall`

There is built-in geocoding:

```dart
const api = 'YOUR_APIKEY';
final String cityName = 'suggested location name';
final String apiKey = 'your api key for OWM';

// use geocoding:
final GeocodingService gService = await GeocodingService(apiKey);
final List<PlaceGeocode> places = gService.getLocationByCityName(cityName);


// use weather service:
final wService = WeatherService(api);
final PlaceGeocode place = places[0];

// get the current weather with use PlaceGeocode
final WeatherOneCall onecall = await 
    wService.oneCallWeatherByLocation(latitude: place.latitude, longitude: place.longitude);
```